# Trying to change font size on button click based on code for BG colour

Tags: javascript, html, colors

I'm trying to teach myself how to design websites with online tutorials, and I copied the code from this video to change background colour on button click. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wj9JpCuMV60

I changed the code to this

```
<button>Switch Colour</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var color = ["#0ff000","#f0ff0f","#000f00","#00f0ff"]
        var i = 0;
        document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", 
        function(){
        i = i < color.length ? ++i : 0;
        document.querySelector("body").style.background = color [i]
        })
    </script>
```

This code works, but when I try to adapt the code to change font family instead, it doesn't do anything.

```
<button>Switch Colour</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var color = ["#0ff000","#f0ff0f","#000f00","#00f0ff"]
            var i = 0;
            document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", 
            function(){
            i = i < color.length ? ++i : 0;
            document.querySelector("body").style.background = color [i]
            })
        </script>
<button>Switch Text Colour</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var font-family = ["Helvetica","Impact"]
            var i = 0;
            document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", 
            function(){
            i = i < font-family.length ? ++i : 0;
            document.querySelector("body").style.body = font-family [i]
            })
        </script>
```

Why does the top code work and the bottom code (mine) doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
document.querySelector("body").style.body = font-family[i]
```

use:

```
document.querySelector("body").style.fontFamily = font-family[i]
```

or:

```
document.body.style.fontFamily = font-family[i]
```

Comment: Neither of those work. Tried with different combos of fontFamily and font-family, too. The bg colour changer still works, just not the font changer